# Android JaCoCo java.io.FileNotFoundException with MVP

Tags: java, android, mvp, jacoco

I'm trying to integrate JaCoCo in my Android app built with MVP pattern, so after I run

```
./gradlew jacocoTestDebugUnitTestReport  --stacktrace
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: PATHTOAPP/Android/App/build/intermediates/classes/debug/com/android/app/mvp/activities/MainActivity$PresentersBinder$applicationPresenter$ViewStateClassNameProvider.class (No such file or directory)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.FileResource.getInputStream(FileResource.java:217)
        at org.jacoco.ant.ReportTask.createBundle(ReportTask.java:569)
        at org.jacoco.ant.ReportTask.createReport(ReportTask.java:542)
        at org.jacoco.ant.ReportTask.execute(ReportTask.java:495)
```

I've tried to google around the web, but found nothin, is there any known workaround?